# Dompdf 1.0 - CSS border property not working?

Tags: php, css, border, dompdf

I am using dompdf 1.0 version to render my html to pdf . css border property is not working for me.
below is my pdf code. (samplepdf.php)

```
<?php

$html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color : blue;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Table With Border</h2>

<p>Use the CSS border property to add a border to the table.</p>

<table style='width:100%'>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>";
$filename = "newpdffile";

// include autoloader
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream($filename,array("Attachment"=>0));
```

Below is the output of my pdf.

[image]

Below is the output of my html code in browzer.

[image]

Problem is border property in css doesnt work in my pdf . Any help? My php version is 7.3.11.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is bug in this version.
I have exactly same problem, so I have already created issue on github https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2331

Comment: This issue was fixed along with release of dompdf 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is problem in new version of dompdf
You should change  your border value
border:1px solid black;
To
border: solid 1px black;
for me it worked!!!
Reference link
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2331#issuecomment-751560493